# Adding click handler to multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kinda new at this jQuery stuff and I've gathered up this much to make my code functional, but I would really want to shorten it. I've already tried $('#Monday','#Tuesday'....) to group them, but with no success.

```
$('#Monday').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $(this).switchClass( "active", "inactive", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).switchClass( "inactive", "active", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function( foo, oldValue ) {return !oldValue});
});
$('#Tuesday').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $(this).switchClass( "active", "inactive", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).switchClass( "inactive", "active", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function( foo, oldValue ) {return !oldValue});
});
$('#Wednesday').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $(this).switchClass( "active", "inactive", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).switchClass( "inactive", "active", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function( foo, oldValue ) {return !oldValue});
});
$('#Thursday').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $(this).switchClass( "active", "inactive", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).switchClass( "inactive", "active", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function( foo, oldValue ) {return !oldValue});
});
$('#Friday').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $(this).switchClass( "active", "inactive", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).switchClass( "inactive", "active", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function( foo, oldValue ) {return !oldValue});
});
$('#Saturday').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $(this).switchClass( "active", "inactive", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).switchClass( "inactive", "active", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function( foo, oldValue ) {return !oldValue});
});
$('#Sunday').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $(this).switchClass( "active", "inactive", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).switchClass( "inactive", "active", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function( foo, oldValue ) {return !oldValue});
});
```

Comment: not going to read all of that, but if ALL of those .`click()` calls have indentical contents, why not just have ONE `$('#Sunday, #Monday, #Tuesday, #blahblahbhal').click(...)` call?

Comment: You say you have used `$('#Monday','#Tuesday'....)` to group them, but that has a syntax error.   There should only be one set of single quotes around the whole thing like Marc B suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a class to all elements, something like .day, and then use that class in your code:

```
$('.day').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $(this).switchClass( "active", "inactive", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).switchClass( "inactive", "active", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function( foo, oldValue ) {return !oldValue});
});
```

Another way would be:

```
$('#Monday, #Tuesday, #Wendnesday').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $(this).switchClass( "active", "inactive", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).switchClass( "inactive", "active", 200, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $(this).parent().find('.miniTime').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function( foo, oldValue ) {return !oldValue});
});
```